# Pm2 don't bind docker ports

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, pm2

Im building a node api boilerplate with docker, babel, istanbul, pm2, eslint and other features. My project works fine in dev mode with nodemon and works fine in test mode with mocha too. However when I run the project in prod mode with pm2 the docker ports don't bind.

The full project can be find here https://github.com/apandrade/node-api-boilerplate

Docker ps result after run in production mode

```
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
    3d5362284957        node:latest         "npm start"              15 seconds ago      Up 15 seconds                                  nodeapiboilerplate_provision_run_1
    a2c79e3e47cc        mongo               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   52 seconds ago      Up 51 seconds       0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp   mongo
```

Base.yml file

```
    version: "2"
    services:
      db_credentials:
        environment:
          - MONGODB_ADMIN_USER=*********
          - MONGODB_ADMIN_PASS=*********
          - MONGODB_APPLICATION_DATABASE=node_api_db
          - MONGODB_APPLICATION_USER=*********
          - MONGODB_APPLICATION_PASS=*********

      common: &common
        image: "node:latest"
        working_dir: /usr/src/app
        restart: always
        volumes:
          - ./:/usr/src/app
          - ./scripts/waitforit:/usr/bin/waitforit
        ports:
          - "3000:3000" 

      base:
        <<: *common
        environment:
          - MONGODB_ADMIN_USER=*********
          - MONGODB_ADMIN_PASS=*********
          - MONGODB_APPLICATION_DATABASE=node_api_db
          - MONGODB_APPLICATION_USER=*********
          - MONGODB_APPLICATION_PASS=*********
          - APP_NAME=node-api-boilerplate
          - PORT=3000
          - DB_HOST=mongo
          - DB_PORT=27017

      base_test:
        <<: *common
        environment:
          - MONGODB_ADMIN_USER=*********
          - MONGODB_ADMIN_PASS=*********
          - MONGODB_APPLICATION_DATABASE=node_api
          - MONGODB_APPLICATION_USER=*********
          - MONGODB_APPLICATION_PASS=*********
          - PORT=3000
          - DB_HOST=mongo
          - DB_PORT=27017
```

docker-compose.yml file

```
    version: "2"
    services:
      mongo:
        container_name: mongo
        image: mongo
        volumes:
          - ./data:/data/db
          - ./scripts/mongo-entrypoint.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-entrypoint.sh
        ports:
          - "27017:27017"
        extends:
          file: base.yml
          service: db_credentials
        command: "mongod --auth"

      develop:
        extends:
          file: base.yml
          service: base
        environment:
          - NODE_ENV=development
          - LOG_LEVEL=debug
        container_name: dev_node_api
        command: "npm run dev"
        depends_on:
          - mongo   

      provision:
        extends:
          file: base.yml
          service: base
        environment:
          - NODE_ENV=production
          - LOG_LEVEL=info
        container_name: prod_node_api
        command: "npm start"
        depends_on:
          - mongo

      test:
        extends:
          file: base.yml
          service: base_test
        environment:
          - NODE_ENV=test
          - LOG_LEVEL=debug
        container_name: test_node_api
        command: "npm run test"
        depends_on:
          - mongo
```

process.json file

```
    {
      "apps" : [{
        "name"        : "node-api-boilerplate",
        "script"      : "./src/server.js",
        "exec_mode"   : "cluster",
        "exec_interpreter": "babel-node",
        "instances" : "max",
        "merge_logs" :true
      }]
    }
```

server.js file

```
    require('pretty-error').start();
    require('babel-register');// eslint-disable-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
    const express = require('express');
    const morgan = require('morgan');
    const methodOverride = require('method-override');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const createError = require('http-errors');
    require('./config/database');
    const router = require('./config/router');
    const logger = require('./config/logger');
    const allowCors = require('./config/cors');

    const PORT = process.env.PORT;
    const app = express();

    app.disable('x-powered-by');
    app.use(methodOverride());

    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(allowCors);

    app.use(morgan('dev', {
        skip: (req, res) => res.statusCode < 400,
        stream: process.stderr,
    }));

    app.use(morgan('dev', {
        skip: (req, res) => res.statusCode >= 400,
        stream: process.stdout,
    }));

    /**
     * Add and remove headers for all requests
     */
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
        next();
    });

    app.use('/api/v1', router);

    /**
     * Error Handler
     */
    app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
        logger.error(err.stack);
        const error = createError(err);
        res.status(error.status).json(error);
        next();
    });


    app.listen(PORT, () => {
        logger.info(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days in search of the solution, I discovery that do not exists any problem, what happens is that to run my project I was run `docker-compose run --rm <service_name>` and the docker compose reference is clear

> the docker-compose run command does not create any of the ports specified in the service configuration. This prevents port collisions with already-open ports. If you do want the service’s ports to be created and mapped to the host, specify the --service-ports flag:

```
docker-compose run --service-ports <service_name>
```

However I chose to run `docker-compose up <service_name>`, it is enough for me because I don't have specific needs how to override a command or run only one container on different ports.